# Python 3: Execute oracle SQL Script containing DDL with indexes and trigger

Tags: python-3.x, ddl, sql-scripts

I have oracle sql script that has create table, index, trigger and grants in single file. I have been doing their execution through sqlplus user/pass@db and then @filepath.sql

how can I execute the sql script from python code, I'm ok if it invokes sqlplus through python.

Comment: There is no quick way to do that. Your best bet is to `open` and `read` the contents of the sql file and split the contents on `";\n"`. That should generate a list of queries you can pass to a `Cursor` object's `execute` method.